# How do you plot a line with two slopes using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using the below codes to plot a line with two slopes as shown in the picture.The slope should should decline after certain limit [limit=5]. I am using vectorisation method to set the slope values.Is there any other method to set the slope values.Could anyone help me in this?

```
                import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
                import numpy as np

                #Setting the condition
                L=5 #Limit
                m=1 #Slope
                c=0 #Intercept

                x=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
                #Calculate the y value
                y=m*x+c

                #plot the line
                plt.plot(x,y)

                #Set the slope values using vectorisation
                m[(x<L)] = 1.0
                m[(x>L)] = 0.75

                # plot the line again
                plt.plot(x,y)

                #Display with grids
                plt.grid()
                plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be overthinking the problem. There are two line segments in the picture:

1. From (0, 0) to (A, A')
2. From (A, A') to (B, B')

You know that `A = 5`, `m = 1`, so `A' = 5`. You also know that `B = 10`. Given that `(B' - A') / (B - A) = 0.75`, we have `B' = 8.75`. You can therefore make the plot as follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
m0 = 1
m1 = 0.75
x0 = 0     # Intercept
x1 = 5     # A
x2 = 10    # B
y0 = 0                    # Intercept
y1 = y0 + m0 * (x1 - x0)  # A'
y2 = y1 + m1 * (x2 - x1)  # B'

plt.plot([x0, x1, x2], [y0, y1, y2])
```

Hopefully you see the pattern for computing y values for a given set of limits. Here is the result:

[image]

Now let's say you really did want to use vectorization for some obscure reason. You would want to compute all the y values up front and plot once, otherwise you will get weird results. Here are some modifications to your original code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Setting the condition
L = 5 #Limit
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
lMask = (x<=L)  # Avoid recomputing this mask

# Compute a vector of slope values for each x
m = np.zeros_like(x)
m[lMask] = 1.0
m[~lMask] = 0.75

# Compute the y-intercept for each segment
b = np.zeros_like(x)
#b[lMask] = 0.0   # Already set to zero, so skip this step
b[~lMask] = L * (m[0] - 0.75)

# Compute the y-vector
y = m * x + b

# plot the line again
plt.plot(x, y)

#Display with grids
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @ Mad Physicist:This is the numerical method way to solve the problem   [more or less like implicit method] wherein the final value of the first line is the initial point for the second line.Your code is numerical method answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Following your code, you should modify the main part like this:

```
x=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
m = np.empty(x.shape)
c = np.empty(x.shape)

m[(x<L)] = 1.0
c[x<L] = 0
m[(x>L)] = 0.75
c[x>L] = L*(1.0 - 0.75)

y=m*x+c

plt.plot(x,y)
```

Note that `c` needs to change as well for the line to be continuous. This is the result: [image]

Comment: Are you sure about your computation of `c`?

Comment: If you are, could you please post an image of the result?

Comment: @ Mad Physicist:The line has to be continuous for any value of slope below 1.

Comment: My mistake, I did not work out the proper formula for the intercept.