# How do you shift a point while ploting a line with two different slopes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, time

I am using the below python codes so as to generate an animated plot for the variable shift point.Here x1 is the shift point which has to be shifted rightwards so as to get plot as shown in the figure below.Here the point x1 is not moving beyond 3 and I am getting in plot window one after another.I need all the plot in one single window.Is there any other method?Could any one help me in this?

Please also refer the link below
[How do you plot a line with two slopes using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727734/how-do-you-plot-a-line-with-two-slopes-using-python)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time
import numpy as np

def ShiftPoint(i):
    x1=0;
    while x1 < i:
        m0 = 1
        m1 = 0.15
        x0 = 0     # Initial x value
        #x1 = 5    # Point to be shifted [Shift Point]
        x2 = 10
        y0 = 0                    
        y1 = y0 + m0 * (x1 - x0)  
        y2 = y1 + m1 * (x2 - x1)
        plt.plot([x0, x1, x2],[y0, y1, y2])
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
        plt.hold()
        time.sleep(0.25)
        x1 += 1
```

[image: Shift Point]

Comment: I haven't checked in a while, but it used to be (and I assume it still is) that repeatedly calling `show()` is *not* the recommended way to create an animation with matplotlib.  Take a look at https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/, or the examples at http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/

Comment: do you want to generate an animation that displays at run time of your code or do you want to generate a movie output of your animation?

Comment: The above codes are meant to plot an animation for the shift in the point x1 at the delay of 0.25 seconds and holding the previous values. The slope of both the lines remain constant and only the x1 is shifted rightwards.This is the plot you get in automotive braking  in cars for variable load conditions.